# Django image does not display in template

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django and i want to import an image to my about.html file

[Both the picture and the about.html are in the same file, see the picture down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyx51.png)

i am trying to insert the image like this, but i get a broken picture icon

```
<img src="templates/WebApp/rolomatik_logo_crna_verzija.png"
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert an image in that way. You need to keep that in a static folder.

Create a folder named `static` and place your image inside it.

Then use `{% load static %}` at the top of your template.

Your img tag should look like this: `<img src="{% static "rolomatik_logo_crna_verzija.png" %}" />`

For more details refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Where exactly i need to put that static file, i am still getting the same broken icon ?

Comment: Django Doc says, store your static files in a folder called **static** in your app. For example **my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg**.

Comment: In your SmartApp folder create a folder named static and place you image inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder `static` in your app. Inside that you have to create another folder with name same as your app name. In your case it should be `SmartApp/static/SmartApp/` and put your image in the folder.

After this use `{% load static %}` at the top of your template,inside your `<head>` tag. After this you can use the image like this:

`<img src="{% static 'SmartApp/rolomatik_logo_crna_verzija.png' %}" >`